# How to add extra column in @ManyToMany relation in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am developing Spring Boot project (2.2.6.RELEASE) with the use of Hibernate ORM (`5.4.x`)

My idea is simple: I want to make a dependency like `@ManyToMany`, but with an additional column (Bidirectional).

For this problem, I created a separate project on the github so that other people who encounter this problem could see where they made a mistake.

For this project I'm using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/all) annotations.

---

**Link to the GitHub**:
[Github Project](https://github.com/Antonio112009/Many-To-Many_with_extra_column)

Entity Relational Diagram
[image link](https://projectlombok.org/features/all)

---

### Error

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [SHORT_CIRCUIT_INDICATOR] value by reflection : [class com.user.manyToMany.entity.PostTagId.tagId] 
setter of com.user.manyToMany.entity.PostTagId.tagId; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [SHORT_CIRCUIT_INDICATOR] 
value by reflection : [class com.user.manyToMany.entity.PostTagId.tagId] setter of com.user.manyToMany.entity.PostTagId.tagId
```

---

#### Update 1:

For the record, this solution works 100% if we are going to make this "unidirectional".
To do that, just exclude following lines:
**Post.java**
 `tag.getPosts().add(postTag);`
`postTag.getTag().getPosts().remove(postTag);`

**Tag.java**
`post.getTags().add(postTag);`
`postTag.getPost().getTags().remove(postTag);`

---

### Test and the code

In the section below, the code and the test that the code does not pass are presented.

### Test that fails

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class PostRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PostTagRepository postTagRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        postRepository.deleteAll();
        postTagRepository.deleteAll();
        tagRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void saveMultiplePostToTag() {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle("Hibernate");
        postRepository.save(post);

        Post post2 = new Post();
        post2.setTitle("High-Performance Java Persistence");
        postRepository.save(post2);

        Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setId(100L);
        tag.setName("business");
        tag.addPost(postRepository.findByTitle("Hibernate"));
        tag.addPost(postRepository.findByTitle("High-Performance Java Persistence"));

        tagRepository.save(tag);

        tag = tagRepository.findByName("business");

        assertNotNull(tag,"checking if tag exists");
        assertEquals("business", tag.getName(),"checking if name exists");
        assertEquals(2, tag.getPosts().size(),"checking if middle table exists");
        assertNotNull(tag.getPosts().get(0).getPost(),"checking if post exists");
        assertNotNull(tag.getPosts().get(1).getPost(),"checking if post exists");
        assertEquals("Hibernate",tag.getPosts().get(0).getPost().getTitle(),"checking if title correct");
    }
}
```

#### Post.java

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "post",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostTag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    public Post() {
    }

    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        PostTag postTag = new PostTag(this, tag);
        tags.add(postTag);
        tag.getPosts().add(postTag);
    }

    public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
        for (Iterator<PostTag> iterator = tags.iterator();
             iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            PostTag postTag = iterator.next();

            if (postTag.getPost().equals(this) &&
                    postTag.getTag().equals(tag)) {
                iterator.remove();
                postTag.getTag().getPosts().remove(postTag);
                postTag.setPost(null);
                postTag.setTag(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Tag.java

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "tag",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostTag> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPost(Post post) {
        PostTag postTag = new PostTag(post, this);
        posts.add(postTag);
        post.getTags().add(postTag);
    }

    public void removePost(Post post) {
        for (Iterator<PostTag> iterator = posts.iterator();
             iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            PostTag postTag = iterator.next();

            if (postTag.getPost().equals(post) && postTag.getTag().equals(this)) {
                iterator.remove();
                postTag.getPost().getTags().remove(postTag);
                postTag.setPost(null);
                postTag.setTag(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### PostTag.java

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class PostTag {

    public PostTag() {}

    public PostTag(Post post, Tag tag) {
        this.post = post;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.id = new PostTagId(post.getId(), tag.getId());
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private PostTagId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("postId")
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("tagId")
    private Tag tag;

    @Column
    private String createdOn;

}
```

#### PostTagId.java

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PostTagId implements Serializable {

    private Long postId;

    private Long tagId;

}
```